# Workspace downloading "error" message while starting client

Tags: iot

I have some trouble when launch AggreGate IoT platform desktop client on the one user PC. After entered password of workspace, have error "Error starting AggreGate Client: Error loading workspace: "0". Re-installing desktop client does not fix the error
Can you help resolve that trouble?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you get "Error loading workspace error" message while starting client try to delete "workspace" subfolder from ".ag" folder (Note: before deleting copy folder to another place). In Windows, you can find it by the path "C:\Users\UserName.ag". After that client application must start without error.